# How do i skip a child in firebase database in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
private void fetchResults() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz").child("Results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Results result = dataSnapshot.getValue(Results.class);
                resultsList.add(result);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

Database has one more child after RESULTS and that is the user unique id of the user... obviously i wont know which user is so how do i skip that child to access the information in it

Database Strucutre - https://ibb.co/mL5KFy

Comment: Can you share the structure of your database and explain a little bit more precisely which exact data you want to fetch. A sub-node of the `Results` node? If yes, are there several such sub-nodes under the `Results` node?

Comment: Hold on a sec il upload the structure

Comment: Look to the edited question please

Comment: which one do you want to skip and how will the result look  like

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Inside your `for` loop, read the data for the specific child/user node with `Results result = childSnapshot.getValue(Results.class);` (note the `childSnapshot` instead of `dataSnapshot`).

Comment: So you want to get the name and score skipping the `Vwtd...qs2` node? This is whay you want? Please responde with: @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the result it in Result.class, get it as a map of String and User

```
private void fetchResults() {
mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz").child("Results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, User> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (map != null) {
                 for (String id: map.entrySet()) {
                      User user = map.get(id);
                      //DO whatever you wan here

                 }
            }
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```